# Android ListView arrays

Tags: android, arrays, database, listview

I'm trying to create a kind of agenda, using a ListView to list the various commitments of the day depending on the time. In the first column of the ListView I visualize an array that contains all hours of the day, and the second column I want to display all the commitments taken from the database.
My problem is to associate the variable `d.ora` to the row corresponding to array `orari`. for example:

```
Listview
8:00
8:30
9:00       9:00
9:30
10:00
10:30     10:30






private class Dettaglio {
    String id;       
    String ora;
}
static final String[] orari = new String[]{
        "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00",
        "10:30"};

private void prova() {
    final List<Dettaglio> dettagli = new ArrayList<appuntamenti.Elenco_appuntamentiFragment.Dettaglio>(25);
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();

    for (int i = 1; i <= orari.length; i++) {
        String prova = "" + i;
        String tabella_op = "SELECT m.id_cliente, m.ora, c.nome, c.cognome FROM Movimenti m LEFT JOIN Clienti" +
                " c ON (m.id_cliente = c._id) AND ora LIKE '" + prova + "'";
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(tabella_op, null);
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();
            d.id = cur.getString(0);
            d.ora = cur.getString(1);
            dettagli.add(d);
        }
        cur.close();
    }
    db.close();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.appuntamenti_row, R.id.timeText, orari) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            String ore = orari[position];
            TextView tvMonth = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
            tvMonth.setText(ore);

            TextView tvAppuntamento;
            tvAppuntamento = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.eventText);
            Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();
            tvAppuntamento.setText(d.ora);

            return row;
        }
    };
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: whats d.ora and orrai? You might need to explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in getView(), you have added Dettaglio object to a list, but while displaying you are not retrieving from the saved list and displaying. You are creating a new instance and displaying its content which would be either the default value or null.

```
        TextView tvAppuntamento;
        tvAppuntamento = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.eventText);
        Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);  //retrieve object from dettagli list
        tvAppuntamento.setText(d.ora);
```

Comment: it works, but if Dettagli d = dettagli.get (position); is empty, I get error outOfBounds. How do I get around this?

Comment: Check it with an `if`: `if (dettagli.size() > 0) {...}`

Comment: Yup...That would work as @Juango suggested..just use dettagli.size()

Answer (score 0):

Use another boolean array to check which time slots are in use:

```
String[] orari = new String[]{"8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30"};
boolean[] ora = new boolean[]{false, false, false, true, false, false, true};
```

Comment: That's an index, so when you access the item at position `i`, you can check `ora[i]` to know if the slot is used or not. Of course, you must populate that array from your database.

Comment: `d.ora` is dynamic, I can not know if it exists or not. So what you say is not good. Read my question. Thank You

Comment: You can build it dynamically. It was just an example.